# An effective way to knock down GSM on demand

Tags: gsm, gprs, 3g

I am building a test rig for a device that has a GSM module to communicate and I want to test how the FW behaves when there is a comms loss and recovery. The GSM module of the device has an antenna connector where I can potentially tap into.

Just disconnecting the antenna doesn't work, because PCB traces some times are enough!

My thought was to have like a T connector and inject noise when I want to simulate loss of signal and then stop injecting to simulate a recovery.

What would be the easiest and most effective way to do this?

Note some devices use GPRS, others 2G, 3G or even 4G.

Edit just a note here, covering the device in some kind of Faraday cage is not possible. I am looking for an automated way of doing this.

Comment: Remove the antenna, put the gadget inside an unplugged microwave oven.

Comment: If you really need to be sure the GSM is out, 2 minutes on high should do it.

Comment: Moving the device is not possible, I am looking for an automated way of doing this.

Comment: "Knock down" should probably be replied with a standard technical term such as "disable" for clarity.

Comment: What does the word "automated" mean to you in this context? Done by robots? Controlled by computer? You need to explain your situation much more fully to get a better answer.

Comment: Microcontroller being ebale to disable the network on command.

Comment: How about a microcontroller that commands a linear actuator to lower a Faraday cage over the device? You still haven't explained why this is completely out of the question for you. I have a feeling there is something you don't want to tell us.

Comment: You could have a Faraday cage on a solenoid or motor. To automate it. Or you could ground the antenna.

Comment: Grounding the antenna, i will try this. What is it that i could possibly not want to tell you? Device could be as small as a 20x30x30 box but as big as 2m tall by 600 by 800 mm. cage must be lifted too high and it's just not convenient.

Answer (score -1):

Buy a 10 bucks GSM/3G/4G radio jammer.

Cheap jammers have a range of 5 meters.

You should switch it on just for the time of your tests.

That's the fastest and cheapest way.

I did it in the past and it works.

To monitor if the comm port works, if the modem is alive and connected, just issue an AT+CSQ? every 12 hours.

Comment: ..are those not illegal to buy and own? Setting up a signal to jam mobile signals is a bit questionable, even in a lab environment. How can you be sure that the jamming is localized and not jamming the phone of a passerby, perhaps even outside the building? Jamming would also trigger other failure modes than a loss of signal.

Comment: Thats the point, this is why I want to inject a signal i to the antenna cable, powerful enough to garbage the communication of the device but not the everyone else's